# When adding @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) the code breaks?

Tags: html, css

The code :

```
/* Header Height Adjustment*/
#ct-header-wrap.ct-header-layout9 .ct-main-menu > li > a {line-height: 89px;}
```

works fine, but it makes a minor adjustment in the mobile version Menu Arrows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLutO.jpg

When trying to contain this change to the laptop version only, by adding the `@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)` */or/ `@media (max-width: 1000px)`* code -the lines `li > a` become red, and that particular code breaks /resets.

```
/* Header Height Adjustment*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
#ct-header-wrap.ct-header-layout9 .ct-main-menu > li > a {line-height: 89px;}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt61j.jpg

Is there something that I miss here?

Thank you very much in advance for any feedback

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Beware the syntax, please try

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #ct-header-wrap.ct-header-layout9 .ct-main-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 89px;
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are not annotations, by the looks of it I assume you have a Java background.

Media queries wrap the rules that are meant to be applied if it matches in `{}`.

So instead of

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
#ct-header-wrap.ct-header-layout9 .ct-main-menu > li > a {line-height: 89px;}
```

it has to be

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #ct-header-wrap.ct-header-layout9 .ct-main-menu > li > a {line-height: 89px;}
}
```